# emacs compilation cannot find source file in some case ("In file included from")

Tags: emacs

Compilation mode works well with error like this :

```
./display.h:899:2: warning: multi-line comment [-Wcomment]
```

but it fails with error like this :

```
In file included from ./internal.h:32:0,                         <-- HERE
                 from world_script/fieldSet.c:33:
./display.h:899:2: warning: multi-line comment [-Wcomment]
```

Make has entered a sub-directory and Emacs has noted it because it offers this message in the minibuffer :

**Find this error in (default ./internal.h:32): /local/wk/michel/conf/cvs/freewrl/freewrl-HEAD/src/lib**

If I make the compilation buffer writable, and I delete the column number to have this line instead :

```
In file included from ./internal.h:32,
```

then it works.

Answer (score 1):

You haven't mentioned what version of Emacs you used.  Maybe this has already been fixed in a later version.  I can confirm this is fixed in the current pretest version of Emacs 24.

See also this wiki page on modifing the regexp used to parse compile errors from the wiki: [CreatingYourOwnCompileErrorRegexp](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/CreatingYourOwnCompileErrorRegexp)

Comment: emacs23 (debian wheezy). Since gcc added column number to its output this has caused trouble in emacs's compilation mode.

Comment: the wiki page explains how to add a new regexp.